# python double inheritance same attributes

Tags: python, class, inheritance, attributes, double

I have a class that inherits from two other classes with the same attribute:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'A'

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'B'

class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self):
        A.__init__(self)
        B.__init__(self)
```

Is there any possibility to rename one attibute inside class C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not trivially. You can't tell a method to skip an assignment, and you can't tell code in a method to use a different attribute name.

You can, of course, have the subclass implement a `__setattr__` hook or `@property` with setter to *intercept* the attribute assignment, but this won't be a solution if the base class also expects to read the attribute again and base further behaviour on the value. Its just easier to either update the code of the base classes or find other ways to implement what you need.

If you are using two base classes that are incompatible like this, then perhaps you are using those base classes wrong.

Your example is trivial enough, but if *both* of those base classes set the same attribute to a mutually incompatible value, then you can't expect the code in either of those classes to work as designed. You can't *rename* the attribute use, both will continue to expect the state of the attributes on `self` to follow their own constraints and so both are basically broken.

For such cases, perhaps you don't actually need to subclass. Perhaps you wanted to use composition instead, where your own custom class stores an instance of the two classes you now use as bases.

Comment: The problem is that i derive from two modules that I have not made by myself. So I can not just rename them

Comment: @Fran.yanno: No, you can't rename their use of attributes. If both use `self.foo` to store state that either expects to do something specific, then those two classes are not compatible and can't used together in a single class. Consider using composition instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can try without inheritance. Make objects inside your C class of A and B.
like this:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'A'

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'B'

class C():
    def __init__(self):        
        self.newA = A()
        self.newB = B()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    my_c = C()
    print(my_c.newB.name)
    print(my_c.newA.name)
```

output:

```
B
A
```